# How to paint a border only around icon/character with CSS?

Tags: css

I've encountered this issue time and time again when using either HTML Characters/Icons/Fonts and I still haven't figured fit that border around the icon a clean way without using pixels.

```css
   div {
      font-size: 5rem;
      display: inline;
    
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: 20%;
    }
```

```html
<div>&times;</div>
```

This just feels wrong and isn't scalable, but this is the end result I want to achieve: *(without using pixels)*

```css
div {
 font-size: 70px;
 display: inline;
 height: 39px;
 line-height: 30px;
 
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>&times</div>
```

**How to make the border fit around the X exactly, no matter whether the font size is 11px, 390% or 111rem.**

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you are looking for?

Comment: You can use line-height with % if you want, like `line-height : 80%`

Comment: @Cam I'm looking for the result of the second example, without using pixels.

Comment: @PascalGoldbach Line height 80% doesn't draw a precise border around a glyph/icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically *impossible* to set once and use many, since different fonts can have their characters aligned differently between the font's ascender height (topline) and descender height (beardline). Read more: [Wikipedia Typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface), [Wikipedia Typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography), [Wikipedia Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font)

The simplest, IMO, is to set the line height to approx. half the font size, and it will work similar no matter font size, and then, some font types might need a *touch* to behave.

*The "X" with the blue border uses `em` and still centers fine*

```css
div {
 font-size: 70px;
 line-height: 0.55;              /*  approx. half font size  */
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 10%;
}

/* sample styling for this demo */
div + div {
 font-size: 140px;
 top: 14%;
 left: 30%;
}
div + div + div {
 font-size: 15em;
 top: 7%;
 left: 60%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>&times</div>
<div>&times</div>
<div>&times</div>
```

---

A side note, and as commented by [Norris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613776/how-to-paint-a-border-only-around-icon-character-with-css/43618507?noredirect=1#comment74347113_43618507), using an SVG could be another option.

Comment: So basically the real answer is - it's impossible. Use SVG Instead :)

Comment: @Norris Yeah :) ... will add a note about that

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the answer, and the pen for it

https://codepen.io/faw/pen/BRQLZe

```css
 div {
   padding: 0;
      font-size: 5rem;
      display: inline;
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: 20%;
   line-height: 2.2rem;
   height: 2.8rem;
     width: 3.rem;
    }
```

```html
<div>&times;</div>
```

Comment: That answers my question literally, but what if the font-size is 3rem, or 8rem, or 19rem? That's still catering directly to specifically measured dimensions. There must be a better way...

*I clarified my question *

Comment: you mean, you are looking for a solution where you must not specify the height and width ? or the line-height ?

Answer (score 0):

The space delimeted by the red border IS actually the space taken by the character (since the font also contains characters that go further up and down, but the official height for every character is alwas the same)

I have a solution for you that uses a pseudo-element to draw the border. I found the settings by trying, but I used percentage values, so at least small to medium changes of the font-size can be handled too. But in the end it will probably depend on the actual font you use and its size.

EDIT: I added a second instance with different font-size, but otherwise identical settings:

```css
div.xxx {
  font-size: 5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}

div.xxx:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}

div.yyy {
  font-size: 25rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

div.yyy:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  bottom: 27%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="xxx">&times;</div>
<div class="yyy">&times;</div>
```